# How does rearrangement work for pulling out factors

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Given $10(6\cdot3+2)$ we can rearrange the equation by pulling out the $3$ and getting $10(\frac{6\cdot3}{3}+\frac{2}{3})3$

Okay I understand that it works. But I don't understand how. I would have assumed to do $10(\frac{6\cdot3}{3}+2)3$ since we are only removing the $3$ as a factor to $6$. Why does $3$ need to be divided by the $2$ as well? $3$ has nothing to do with the $2$.

Comment: The only way the value of the expression will be unchanged is if you both multiply and divide by $3$.

Comment: Notice that everything in the parentheses is being multiplied by $10$.  If you extract a $3$ from the parentheses, each term left in the parentheses is being multiplied by $30$.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).